# setBackgroundDrawableForDate caldroid not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite, caldroid

Hey im trying to do something like , when user clicks the button it gets  the data from a dataBase column , named Datas in a for loop, it runs the for loop as many time as the maxID (if the max id is 10(10 dates) it runs 10 times) . Well and whit that data it took from that database they setBackgroundDrawableForDate(blue,(that date it took from database)).Its not doing that setBackgroundDrawableForDate and I don't know why. Here is my code :

ClickListener that is called when user clicks the button:

```
      add_test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            boolean isInserted = myDB.insertData("Portugues", sala_text.getText().toString(), dt, hora2);
                if (isInserted){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Teste inserido ao calendario",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    date_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    hora_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    date_text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    sala_text.setText("");
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Preencha todos os espaços",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            myCF.addToCalendar();
        }
        });

    }

}
```

Method that is called when user clicks by the ClickListener:

```
     public void addToCalendar(){

    myDB = CustomApplication.getDatabaseHelper();
    ColorDrawable blue = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE);
    for(int i=0;i == myDB.getLastId();i++){
        String dt = myDB.getDates(i);
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date teste = null;
        try {
            teste = sdf.parse(dt);
            caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(blue,teste);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Methods that are called for getting the maxID and all the dates in the dataBASE :

```
        public int getLastId() {
    String query = "SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
    int id = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            id = cursor.getInt(0);
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return id;

}

public String getDates(int id){
    String date = "";
    String last_query = "SELECT " + COL_4  + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME  + " WHERE " + COL_1 + " = '" + id + "'";
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(last_query, null);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst())
    {
        date = c.getString(0); // Return Value
    }
    c.close();
    return date;
}
```

}

Comment: try debugging your app to see where it goes wrong https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html#breakPoints

Comment: Oh ty EpicPandaForce! I will check that but I don't have any errors so I don't know how to do it .

Comment: Well you *do* have behavior that doesn't behave as you expect, so you should check out where what you expect doesn't happen :D

Comment: Oh ok i will try it ! Thanks !

Comment: Well I don't understand anything of that its just a bunch of phrases like I told you before im a youtube learning really noob

Comment: Can I check whats the value of id ?

Comment: So , getID() seems to be working perfectly

Comment: But in getData I receive this : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Invalid argument count: expected 1, received 0

Comment: Can you guess it PandaForce?

Comment: What is `getData()`?

Comment: getDates im sorry

Comment: In Portuguese Dates stands for "Data" is a very strange language